# GTK detailed_signal

Tags: gtk

Where can I find a list of detailed_signal (used in g_signal functions)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [index](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/api-index-full.html). Signals are indicated by `ClassName::signal-name`.

You don't have to use the signal detail in `g_signal` functions though - most signals don't have details. The only one I regularly use is `GObject::notify`.

Connect to a non-detailed signal like this:

```
g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(on_button_clicked), data);
```

Connect to a detailed signal like this:

```
g_signal_connect(button, "notify::label", G_CALLBACK(on_button_label_notify), data);
```

Comment: Thanks! I had not seen api-index.